# Flatlist have multiple textinput but state not updating

Tags: textinput, react-native-flatlist

I need to ask how to change the state of every text Input if they are in a Flat List with each item separately. According to the item i want to store that text Input value. Here is my code. This is my code i need to save data and want to update the qty according to the item id.

```
 constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.saveData = this.saveData.bind(this);
this.UpdateValue = this.UpdateValue.bind(this);



this.state = {

  showToast: false,

  qty: 0,
  title: 'save',
  product: [],
  dataSource: [
    {
      id: 1, qty: 0, title: 'Black Hat', categoryId: 5, categoryTitle: 'MEN', price: 22, image: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/atf19/image/upload/c_crop,h_250,w_358,x_150/v1500465309/pexels-photo-206470_nwtgor.jpg', description: "Hello there, i'm a cool product with a heart of gold."

    },
    { id: 2, qty: 0, title: 'V Neck T-Shirt', categoryId: 2, categoryTitle: 'WOMEN', price: 12, image: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/atf19/image/upload/c_crop,h_250,x_226,y_54/v1500465309/pexels-photo-521197_hg8kak.jpg', description: "Hello there, i'm a cool product with a heart of gold." },
    { id: 10, qty: 0, title: 'Black Leather Hat', categoryId: 1, categoryTitle: 'KIDS', price: 2, image: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/atf19/image/upload/c_crop,g_face,h_250,x_248/v1500465308/fashion-men-s-individuality-black-and-white-157675_wnctss.jpg', description: "Hello there, i'm a cool product with a heart of gold." },
    { id: 15, qty: 0, title: 'Long Sleeves T-Shirt', categoryId: 5, categoryTitle: 'MEN', price: 120, image: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/atf19/image/upload/c_crop,h_250,x_100,y_50/v1500465308/pexels-photo-500034_uvxwcq.jpg', description: "Hello there, i'm a cool product with a heart of gold." },
    { id: 11, qty: 0, title: 'Pink Diamond Watch', categoryId: 5, categoryTitle: 'MEN', price: 22, image: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/atf19/image/upload/c_crop,h_250/v1500465308/pexels-photo-179909_ddlsmt.jpg', description: "Hello there, i'm a cool product with a heart of gold." },
    { id: 22, qty: 0, title: 'Golden Tie', categoryId: 2, categoryTitle: 'WOMEN', price: 12, image: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/atf19/image/upload/c_scale,w_300/v1500284127/pexels-photo-497848_yenhuf.jpg', description: "Hello there, i'm a cool product with a heart of gold." },
    { id: 100, qty: 0, title: 'Black Pearl Earrings', categoryId: 1, categoryTitle: 'KIDS', price: 2, image: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/atf19/image/upload/c_crop,g_center,h_250/v1500465307/pexels-photo-262226_kbjbl3.jpg', description: "Hello there, i'm a cool product with a heart of gold." },
    { id: 215, qty: 0, title: 'Grey Blazer', categoryId: 5, categoryTitle: 'MEN', price: 120, image: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/atf19/image/upload/c_scale,w_300/v1500284127/pexels-photo-497848_yenhuf.jpg', description: "Hello there, i'm a cool product with a heart of gold." },
    { id: 12, qty: 0, title: 'Mirror Sunglasses', categoryId: 5, categoryTitle: 'MEN', price: 22, image: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/atf19/image/upload/c_crop,g_face,h_250/v1500465307/pexels-photo-488541_s0si3h.jpg', description: "Hello there, i'm a cool product with a heart of gold." },
    { id: 29, qty: 0, title: 'White Shirt', categoryId: 2, categoryTitle: 'WOMEN', price: 12, image: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/atf19/image/upload/c_scale,w_300/v1500284127/pexels-photo-497848_yenhuf.jpg', description: "Hello there, i'm a cool product with a heart of gold." },
    { id: 16, qty: 0, title: 'Tie', categoryId: 1, categoryTitle: 'KIDS', price: 2, image: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/atf19/image/upload/c_scale,w_300/v1500284127/pexels-photo-497848_yenhuf.jpg', description: "Hello there, i'm a cool product with a heart of gold." }
  ]
}
```

}

```
 async saveData(item) {
console.log("We are in Save function")
var product = [];

var items = {
  id: item.id,
  title: item.title,
  image: item.image,
  price: item.price,
  description: item.description,
  qty:  this.state.qty,
  categoryTitle: item.categoryTitle,
}


const value1 = await AsyncStorage.getItem("Cart");

if (value1 === "" || value1 === null) {
  product.push(items);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(product));
  AsyncStorage.setItem("Cart", JSON.stringify(product));
}

else if (items.qty <= 0 || items.qty == "" || items.qty == "undefined") {


  //ToastAndroid.show('please enter quantity!', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
  alert("pls enter quantity")
}

else {

  var prodsArr = JSON.parse(value1);
  for (var i = 0; i < prodsArr.length; i++) {
    var item = prodsArr[i];
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(item))
    if (item.id === items.id) {
      return (
        this.setState({


        }), alert(qty)

      )
      prodsArr.push(items)
      AsyncStorage.setItem("Cart", JSON.stringify(prodsArr))
    }
  }

  prodsArr.push(items); 
   console.log(JSON.stringify(prodsArr));
  AsyncStorage.setItem("Cart", JSON.stringify(prodsArr))
  ToastAndroid.show('item added!', ToastAndroid.SHORT);

}
```

}

```
 UpdateValue = (update) => {

this.setState({ qty: update })
this.update = update;
```

}

renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {

```
return (

  <ListItem>
    <View>

      <Image style={{ width: 280, height: 250 }} source={{ uri: item.image }} />


      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', margin: 5 }}>

        <TextInput

          keyboardType="numeric"
          multiline={false}
          value={this.state.qty}
          onChangeText={this.UpdateValue.bind(this)}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent" placeholder="0"
          style={{ height: 30, width: 50, borderWidth: 0.5, borderColor: 'cyan', justifyContent: 'center' }}
        />

      </KeyboardAvoidingView>

      <Button title={this.state.title} onPress={this.saveData.bind(this, item)}> </Button>

      <Button title="Cart" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Second')} />

    </View>
  </ListItem>

);
```

}

render() {

```
return (

  <View>

    <FlatList
      data={this.state.dataSource}
      renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
      keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
    />
  </View>
)
```

}
};

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Assuming you have data stored in state as an array of objects and are rendering TextInput items for each one, I think the easiest thing would be to add a key to each object dedicated to the input value (i.e. `data: [{id: 1, placeholder: 'text', inputValue: '...'}]`) and update that value using the `onChangeText` TextInput prop and checking against the item id. As long as you're careful to observe state immutability while doing so it should work fine.

Comment: @swimisbell  please check the code and please let me know how can i do that, i tried but may be not in right way please guide me or give me an example, thanks in advance. :)